How do I autosize text boxes to their contents in a Slides presentation?
Autosize text boxes in Google Slides
I want to be able to autosize text boxes to their contents in my Slides presentations.
When there are a lot of text boxes in a presentation, manually adjusting their width using the handles when created and also each time their text changes is a lot of work.
Slides does have a setting 'Resize shape to fit text' in the Autofit menu, but it only resizes the shape's height, not its width. * see first image
Is there any setting in Google Slides that configures a text box to autosize both its height and width whenever its text changes, or even a way to do it on a one-off/as-needed basis using a keyboard shortcut or a menu option?
Slides 'Resize shape to fit text' option doesn't adjust the width
Examples in other applications

In Adobe Illustrator you can double-click on a handle to resize a text box:

Adtl. resource: "I overlooked this Illustrator feature at first – now it saves me time & headaches" 
In Draw.io (app.diagrams.net) the Arrange menu
has a one-time/as-needed Autosize option
KB Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Y

Adtl. resource: @thomas-the-tank-engine's answer "How to resize a draw.io text box automatically..." 

Crossposted to Google Docs Editors Community Support

Thank you very much, highly appreciate it.
